# NullPointer Java Mesmo tendo inicializado a variável

Tags: java, javafx

eu estou tendo um problema para Setar um label de outro controller, meu projeto está estruturado da seguinte forma: FilmeOverviewController, é o overview que contém uma tableview, nessa tableview você pode selecionar o filme e etc,  aí eu criei um handle para um botão que pega esses atributos dos filmes e existe outra classe chamada Sala, em que há alguns atributos (se é 3d, capacidade e etc) porém, não consigo de forma alguma utilizar os atributos contidos nessa outra sala, mesmo inicializando a mesma, sempre tenho NullPointer ou algo parecido, alguém sabe o que posso fazer pra consertar isso?

Segue o código da classe FilmeOverviewController e a classe sala respectivamente:

```
public class FilmeOverviewController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Filmes> filmeTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Filmes, String> nomeColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Filmes, String> categoriaColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Filmes, String> salaColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label nomeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label salaLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label categoriaLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label diretorLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label duracaoLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label protagonistaLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label classificacaoLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label capacidadeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label disponivelLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label is3dLabel;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton venderIngresso;


    // referencia a classe main
    private MainApp mainApp;


    public FilmeOverviewController() {
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        //Inicia a tableview com tres colunas.
        nomeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nomeProperty());
        categoriaColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().categoriaProperty());
        salaColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getSala());
        // limpando os detalhes
        showFilmeDetails(null);
        // adicionando funcao
        filmeTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showFilmeDetails(newValue));

    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        //adiciona uma observable list
        filmeTable.setItems(mainApp.getfilmeDados());
    }


    private void showFilmeDetails(Filmes filme) {
        if (filme != null) {
            nomeLabel.setText(filme.getNome());
            categoriaLabel.setText(filme.getCategoria());
            duracaoLabel.setText(filme.getDuracao());
            protagonistaLabel.setText(filme.getProtagonista());
            classificacaoLabel.setText(filme.getClassificacao());
            diretorLabel.setText(filme.getDiretor());
            salaLabel.setText(filme.getSalaNumero());
            capacidadeLabel.setText(Integer.toString(filme.getCapacidade()));
            disponivelLabel.setText(Integer.toString(filme.getDisp()));
            if (filme.get3D() == true) {
                is3dLabel.setText("Sim");
            } else {
                is3dLabel.setText("Não");
            }
        } else {
            nomeLabel.setText("");
            categoriaLabel.setText("");
            duracaoLabel.setText("");
            protagonistaLabel.setText("");
            classificacaoLabel.setText("");
            diretorLabel.setText("");
            salaLabel.setText("");
            capacidadeLabel.setText("");
            disponivelLabel.setText("");
            is3dLabel.setText("");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleDeletarFilme() {
        int selectedIndex = filmeTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            filmeTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        } else {
            Alert alerta = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alerta.setTitle("Nenhum filme selecionado");
            alerta.setHeaderText("Nenhuma Selecao");
            alerta.setContentText("Por favor selecione um filme para deletar");
            alerta.showAndWait();
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleNovoFilme() {
        Filmes tempFilme = new Filmes("Nome","Categoria");
        boolean clicado = mainApp.showEditarFilmeDialog(tempFilme);
        if (clicado) {
            mainApp.getfilmeDados().add(tempFilme);
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleEditarFilme() {
        Filmes filmeSelecionado = filmeTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if(filmeSelecionado != null) {
            boolean clicado = mainApp.showEditarFilmeDialog(filmeSelecionado);
            if(clicado) {
                showFilmeDetails(filmeSelecionado);
            }
        }else {
            //se nada for selecionado
            Alert alerta = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alerta.initOwner(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());
            alerta.setTitle("Nenhuma selecao");
            alerta.setHeaderText("Nenhum filme selecionado");
            alerta.setContentText("Por favor selecione algum filme.");
            alerta.showAndWait();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void handleVenderIngresso() throws IOException {

          Filmes filmeSelecionado = filmeTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
          FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("resources/VenderIngresso.fxml"));
            AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            //criar o stage

            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Vender Ingresso");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            //chamando o controlador

            VenderIngressoController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);


            //mostrando o dialog e esperando ate fecharem
            dialogStage.showAndWait();

        }
}
```

---

```
public class Sala {
    private boolean e3d;
    private int assentosMax;
    private int assentosDisp;
    private final StringProperty numeroProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();


    public Sala(boolean e3d, int assentosMax, int assentosDisp, String numero) {
        setNumero(numero);
        e3d = this.e3d;
        assentosMax = this.assentosMax;
        assentosDisp = this.assentosDisp;
    }
    public boolean is3d() {
        return e3d;
    }
    public void setE3d(boolean e3d) {
        this.e3d = e3d;
    }
    public int getAssentosMax() {
        return assentosMax;
    }
    public void setAssentosMax(int assentosMax) {
        this.assentosMax = assentosMax;
    }
    public int getAssentosDisp() {
        return assentosDisp;
    }
    public void setAssentosDisp(int assentosDisp) {
        this.assentosDisp = assentosDisp;
    }
    public StringProperty numeroProperty() {
        return numeroProperty;
    }
    public final String getNumero() {
        return numeroProperty.get();
    }
    public final void setNumero(String numero) {
        numeroProperty().set(numero);
    }



}
```

Assim, eu criei um controller em que eu quero pegar os atributos do filme selecionado e colocar nos textfield dele:

```
public class VenderIngressoController {
    @FXML
    private Label tituloLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label salaLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label categoriaLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label diretorLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label duracaoLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label protagonistaLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label classificacaoLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label e3dLabel;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton gerarIngresso;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton cancelarIngresso;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox meiaEntradaBox;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField precoEspecialField;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkPrecoEspecial;

    private Filmes filme;

    private Stage dialogStage;
    private int precoEspecial;

    public int getPrecoEspecial() {
        return precoEspecial;
    }
    public void setPrecoEspecial(int precoEspecial) {
        this.precoEspecial = precoEspecial;
    }
    public int getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }
    public void setPreco(int preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
    public int getMeiaEntrada() {
        return meiaEntrada;
    }
    public void setMeiaEntrada(int meiaEntrada) {
        this.meiaEntrada = meiaEntrada;
    }

    private int preco;
    private int meiaEntrada;


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }
    public void setDialogStage(Stage dialogStage) {
        this.dialogStage = dialogStage;

    }

    public void VenderIngresso(Filmes filme) {
        this.filme = filme;
        tituloLabel.setText(filme.getNome());
        salaLabel.setText(filme.getSalaNumero());
        categoriaLabel.setText(filme.getCategoria());
        diretorLabel.setText(filme.getDiretor());
        duracaoLabel.setText(filme.getDuracao());
        protagonistaLabel.setText(filme.getProtagonista());
        classificacaoLabel.setText(filme.getClassificacao());
        if (filme.get3D() == true) {
            e3dLabel.setText("Sim");
        } else {
            e3dLabel.setText("Não");
        }

    }
    public void setCategoria (String nome) {
        categoriaLabel.setText(nome);
    }
    @FXML
    void handleCancelarIngresso(ActionEvent event) {
        dialogStage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    void handleGerarIngresso(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

Dessa forma, o que eu tentei fazer foi o seguinte: `venderIngressoController.setCategoria(filmeSelecionado.getCategoria());`
Porém, isso me retorna um NullPointer, alguém sabe o que eu posso fazer para consertar? Tentei o stackoverflow americano e não consegui encontrar uma dúvida parecida com 2 controllers.
Edit: Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projeto.resources.EditarFilmeController.setFilme(EditarFilmeController.java:65)
    at projeto.MainApp.showEditarFilmeDialog(MainApp.java:105)
    at projeto.resources.FilmeOverviewController.handleEditarFilme(FilmeOverviewController.java:145)
    ... 62 more
```

Da mesma forma como eu coloquei ali em cima, eu tentei utilizar         `capacidadeField.setText(Integer.toString(filme.getCapacidade()));` em outra classe e tive o mesmo problema, porém, não consigo descobrir já que eu inicializei a variável

Comment: Onde está a linha `venderIngressosController.setCategoria(filmeSelecionado.getCategoria());`? Não achei no código-fonte fornecido.

Comment: Eu tirei pra testar se era essa chamada que causava o erro e realmente era, vou postar adicionar o stacktrace

Comment: Eu tive um problema semelhante uma vez e passar informações de um controller para o outro é um pouco difícil. Há a opção de criar um controller com um parâmetro mas isso não te ajudaria muito. Usar um banco de dados talvez?

Comment: O NPE pode acontecer também se você der setText(null), ou seja, filme.getCategoria() retorna null. Não parece ser este o caso mas é só pra resaltar que pode não ser problemas de inicialização de variáveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, o melhor jeito de enviar informação de uma Controladora1 pra Controladora2, é usando os construtores das classes passando como parámetro a Controladora1 no construtor da Controladora2. Desse jeito vc consegue acessar a qualquer método e variável públicas da Controladora1 na Controladora2.

exemplo:

```
/**
 * Neste exemplo o que vou fazer é pegar a informação de um 
 * textField da classe Controller1 e mostrar na classe Controller2 
 * usando o metodo getText() da classe Controller1 na classe Controller2
 **/ 

//class Controladora 1
public class Controller1{

@FXML
private TextField txtNome;

@FXML
private Button btnEnviar;

public Controller1(){}

@FXML
void actionBtnEnviar(ActionEvent evt){ //Action do botão
   new Controller2(Controller1.this); //Chamada da classe Controller2 passando class Controller1
}

//Método pra obter o valor do TextField
public String getText(){
  return txtNome.getText();//retornar o valor do TextField
}

}

//-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

//Controladora 2
public class Controller2{

@FXML
private TextField txtNome;


public Controller1 controller1;

//Contructor da classe
public Controller2(Controller1 controller1){

 this.controller1 = controller1;
}

 @FXML
 private void initialize() {
    if(controller1 !=null)// verificar controller1 nao esteja vacio
      System.out.println(controller1.getText());// print na console o valor do textField

     else
      System.out.println("Texto vacio");//print vacio caso controller1 esteja vacio
 }
}
```