# Problema na passagem de parâmetros entre telas no JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

Amigos, esse é o metodo start da minha main de um projeto JavaFX. A ideia era que eu guardasse uma cache de todas as telas para que eu pudesse fazer a passagem de objetos entre as telas através do observer pattern. O método de passagem é o "ChangeScreen".

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        stage = primaryStage;

        primaryStage.setTitle("MyApp");
        AnchorPane fxmlLogin = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/ViewLogin.fxml"));
        LoginScene = new Scene(fxmlLogin,1077,720);

        AnchorPane fxmlAlterDados = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/AlterarDadosView.fxml"));
        AlterDadosScene = new Scene(fxmlAlterDados,1078,720);

        AnchorPane fxmlMain = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/ViewMainUsuario.fxml"));
        MainScene = new Scene(fxmlMain, 1077, 720);

        AnchorPane fxmlDetalhes = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/quixada/ufc/fbd/view/DetalhesPontoTurisiticoView.fxml"));
        DetalhesScene = new Scene(fxmlDetalhes, 1077, 720);

        primaryStage.setScene(LoginScene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 public static void changeScreen(String scr, Object userData) {
    switch (scr) {
    case "login":
        stage.setScene(LoginScene);
        notifyAllListeners("login", userData);
        break;
    case "cadastro":
        stage.setScene(CadastroScene);
        notifyAllListeners("cadastro", userData);
        break;
    case "main":
        stage.setScene(MainScene);
        notifyAllListeners("main", userData);
        break;
    case "alterDados":
        stage.setScene(AlterDadosScene);
        notifyAllListeners("alterDados", userData);
    }
}

public static void changeScreen(String scr) {
    changeScreen(scr, null);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public static void addOnChangeScreenListener(OnChangeScreen newListener) {
    listeners.add(newListener);
}

private static void notifyAllListeners(String newScreen, Object userData) {
    for (OnChangeScreen l : listeners)
        l.onScreenChanged(newScreen, userData);
}
}
```

Ao realizar o login, o banco irá retornar uma instancia de usuário correspondente para que este possa ser passado para tela principal do usuário. A partir desse objeto passado para a tela principal, seria carregado, a partir dele os labels que teriam o nome e a idade do mesmo.
Porém, o problema é que, ao executar essa ação, ocorre um problema de NullPointerException.

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    MainJavaFX.addOnChangeScreenListener(new OnChangeScreen() {

        @Override
        public void onScreenChanged(String newScreen, Object userData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            userNow = (Turista) userData;
        }
    });
     idNameLabel.setText(userNow.getTnome());
     String idade = Integer.toString(userNow.getTidade());
     idIdadeLabel.setText(idade);
```

Alguém poderia me dar alguma idéia ou solução para me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: Você poderia colocar o objeto Usuário como variável static na classe principal da sua aplicação. É difícil passar parametros entre telas FXML.

Comment: acho que definir variáveis **static** para a comunicação entre telas, não ser uma boa prática. Uma boa prática é o uso dos ***construtores das classes*** para enviar qualquer informação, até executar métodos. Eu ja tinha respondido uma pergunta igual neste forum, da uma olhada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307343/65598